# OO Calc: Detecting Blank Cells and Replacing with Cell above?

Tags: openoffice, openoffice-calc

So annoyed I can't find a simple answer to this simple question!

I'm using OpenOffice Calc.  I want a formula which will detect if the cell is blank, and if it is to replace it with the contents in the cell above it.

I guess the best way to do this is create a new blank column, put formulae in there.  Then copy the formula results and paste into original column as plain text.

```
Column A        : Column B (formula column)

Joe               Joe
Bloggs            Bloggs
Mack              Mack
                  Mack
                  Mack
Peter             Peter
John              John
                  John
Joe               Joe
```

Something like this:

`=IF(A2="",A1)` or `=IF(ISBLANK(A2);A1)`

Can't seem to get formulae to work and I only get an error (err:508 / err:509).

Comment: Have you thought about a macro?

Comment: I'm not really that knowledgeable with Macros :( Although I don't see why the above wouldn't work just as good...

Comment: Me either but I know they can do repetitive tasks within a range so sound like your answer.  We await the experts:)

Comment: Verify that OO Calc allows you to leave off the last argument.  Either =IF(A2-"",A1,A2) or =IF(ISBLANK(A2),A1,A2) should work.  One other thing to check: just learned that OO Calc does some unique things with formula delimiters (";" instead of "," in some cases).  Verify that in your formulas.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `VLOOKUP` with a floating range to retrieve the last text value in a column.

[image: VLOOKUP last text value]

The formula in B1 is,

`=VLOOKUP("zzzz"; A$1:A1; 1)`

Fill down as necessary.

Using `VLOOKUP` for an approximate match usually requires that the data in the lookup column be sorted. That is not the case here as we are using *zzzz* as the lookup value to catch the last available text value in column A from the current position. The current position is constructed by locking the row of the first portion of the `A$1:A1` and allowing the latter portion to 'float'. This produces `A$1:A1`, `A$1:A2`, `A$1:A3`, etc as it is filled down.